# To find eigenvalues and eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I am asked to find the eigenvector of the matrix

$$ \begin{bmatrix}  1 &  8\\
                  0  & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

It's very easy. I found eigenvalues as $(1,1)$. And eigenvector as
           $$x_1=1 \text{ and } x_2=0.$$
But what's wrong with the answer!!The answer is given as $(5,0)^T$.
                                                                              $T$ stands for transpose. Doesn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eigenvector is not unique, multiple of an eigenvector is still an eigenvector.

Suppose $v$ is an eigenvector, $k$ is a non-zero scalar, and $\lambda$ is the corresponding eigenvalue.

$$A(kv)=k(Av)=k\lambda v = \lambda (kv)$$

Comment: But I have given 4 options and only one is correct.

Comment: Are the rest a scalar multiple of $(1,0)$?

Comment: No...There is none except (5,0)^T. But what difference does it make?

Comment: You have solved the problem and obtain the result that non-zero scalar multiples of $(1,0)$ are the eigenvectors. what makes you think that the others are eigenvectors? You can try to multiply the other solution with the matrix and check if they satisfy $Av=\lambda v$.

Comment: .Got it. thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

After concluding $1$ is an eigenvalue, how did you try to find the eigenvector? I suppose you did the following:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 8 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
v_1 \\
v_2
\end{bmatrix} =
1\begin{bmatrix}
v_1 \\
v_2
\end{bmatrix}
$$

From this, we have the following two equations:
$$
1v_1+8v_2 = v_1\text{ and } v_2 = v_2.
$$

The second one does not tell anything useful to us, so we can disregard it. The first one tells us that $v_2 = 0$. Note that no constraint was imposed on $v_1$. For any real value of $v_1$ the two equations above are satisfied. This means there are a infinite number of eigenvalues of the form:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
v_1 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}, \,\,\, v_1 \in \mathbb{R}.
$$